# Check key exist in nested subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm using MongoDB Java driver 3.2 and trying to check if an field exist in a nested sub document. I have to take some really awkward approach. For example:

```
ObjectId oid = new ObjectId();
Document newDoc = new Document("_id", oid);
newDoc.append("c_doc", new Document("cid", "child document").append("co", "obj"));
String testKey = "c_doc.cid";
if (newDoc.containsKey(testKey)) {
    System.out.println("exist");
} else {
    System.out.println("not exist");
}
if (newDoc.get(testKey) != null) {
    System.out.println("get exist");
} else {
    System.out.println("get null");
}
if (((Document)newDoc.get("c_doc")).containsKey("cid")){
    System.out.println("get and check: exist");
} else {
    System.out.println("get and check: not exist");
}
```

The first two approaches to check if key *cid* exists in sub document of *c_doc* are intuitive but failed. Only the 3rd one works but it's awkward. My real data has one more sub document to go into.

I have to write a utility function to do this check, but I think it shouldn't be this ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Document` is essentially a `Map` and doesn't support dotted syntax like `testKey` so you'll have to manually walk it down like you have.